# assign variable to label inside a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a variable "mininum" that needs to be assigned to a label "minLabel", his label is inside a template view which is inside a gridview. When try minLabel.text= mininum it I get the error that the label does not exist. How do I reference the label so that I can assign the variable to it?

Thanks

```
            studentGrid.Parent.FindControl("minLabel")
            minLabel.Text = minObject

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class min">
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:Label ID="minLabel" runat="server"                Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                  </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: At which event you want to set value to your label,it's on page load or on another event..

Comment: I want to set it on page load.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a value of a control placed inside grid view like you mentioned

> minLabel.text= mininum

This is the way to find control inside gridview...

```
protected void studentGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           (Label)e.Row.FindControl("minLabel").Text = "mininum";
        }
    }
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to the label first. Use:

```
myGrid.Parent.FindControl("minLabel");
```

Then, proceed as usual.

Comment: Label still is not declared, I've updated code to show what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
GridView.FindControl(string id);
```